# 2D Horror Game Flashlight

Tags: graphic-effects

I'm trying to make a 2D horror game, which some can argue are less scary than 3D horror games. To compensate, I'm trying to make everything around the character dark except for a circle around the player. How can I accomplish this with paint?

I can draw over the background with black, and make the darkness move when the player does, but how can I make the light around him circular?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) StackOverflow users are not there to build your application or write the code in your place. What development language do you use ? What have you tried so far ? You should ask a more specific question showing that you made some efforts to search for answers by yourself first : [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @IvanGabriele All your questions are already answered by OP either in plain text or via tags. I think this question is very valid, it is simply not a code-level question but a more abstract graphics programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a black image and create a transparent circle in the center. Then you just need to stick the center of the image to your character.

Comment: Do you know any free softwares to remove part of an image to make it transparent? The only software I know cost money and my subscription ran out, so I can't use it anymore.

Comment: Use GIMP and some tutorials. It has the same capabilities as photoshop.